# How to grep information?

Tags: shell, grep

What I have:

```
test
more text
@user653434 text and so


test
more text
@user9659333 text and so
```

I'd like to filter this text and finally get the following list as .txt file:

```
user653434
user9659333
```

It's important to get the names without "@" sign.
Thx for help ;)

Comment: Is the name always starting with an `@` and is that the only info in the file that starts with an `@`?

Comment: Yes :) It always starts with @ and there is no more @ in the text, just at beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `grep -P` (requires GNU `grep`):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=@)\w+' File
user653434
user9659333
```

`-o` tells grep to print only the match.

`-P` tells grep to use Perl-style regular expressions.

`(?<=@)` tells sed that `@` must precede the match but the `@` is not included in the match.

`\w+` matches one or more word characters.  This is what grep will print.

To change the file in place with `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=@)\w+' File >tmp && mv tmp File
```

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -En 's/^@([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1/p' File
user653434
user9659333
```

And, to change the file in place:

```
sed -En -i.bak 's/^@([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1/p' File
```

`-E` tells sed to use the extended form of regular expressions.  This reduces the need to use escapes.

`-n` tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.

`-i.bak` tells sed to change the file in place while leaving a backup file with the extension `.bak`.

The leading `s` in `s/^@([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1/p` tells sed that we are using a *substitute* command.  The command has the typical form `s/old/new/` where `old` is a regular expression and sed replaces `old` with `new`.  The trailing `p` is an option to the substitute command: the `p` tells sed to print the resulting line.

In our case, the `old` part is `^@([[:alnum:]]+).*`.  Starting from the beginning of the line, `^`, this matches `@` followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, `([[:alnum:]]+)`, followed by anything at all, `.*`.  Because the alphanumeric characters are placed in parens, this is saved as a group, denoted `\1`.

The `new` part of the substitute command is just `\1`, the alphanumeric characters from above which comprise the user name.

Here, the `s` indicates that we are using a sed *substitute* command. The usual form

Comment: And finally how to overwrite the file with the new output? :]

Comment: @hannir: use GNU `sed`.

Comment: @hannir I updated the answer with info for overwriting the file with both `grep` and, as Cyrus suggested, `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '^@\K[^ ]*' file
```

Output:

```
user653434
user9659333
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)